# Download file from FTP server in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have some files on my FTP server. Now I want to allow the user to download the file.
How can i do that?

I searched a lot on internet but could not found some helpful.

Note : I am using MVC5 and angularjs

I have tried this:

```
var  filePath = "FTP_FILE_PATH";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + "new");
        return File(filePath, "audio/mp3");
```

Comment: **No free coding service.**

Comment: Why are the files on an FTP server if you don't want to use FTP? *download the file* what do you mean? You want to provide an FTP address or you want your web server to FTP the files then provide a download link or stream them directly into the response? It'd make a lot more sense if you just put the "files" onto your web server and just provide links to them. Overall this question isn't very clear and lacks effort

Comment: [this Can help you](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Download-Files-from-FTP-Web-Server-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Comment: So you want to fetch them from the FTP server and then pass them to the user as the response to the user's HTTP request to the MVC app, is that right? Firstly download the file from the FTP server (sure you can google some C# for that) and then offer the file (or a stream of the contents, if that's easier) for download from your app (you seem to have got some basics of the code for that already). You can't just stick an `ftp://` link as the filename, that makes no sense. I guess also probably the user doesn't have direct access to the FTP server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the `filename` parameter of the [`File`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.file(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.File%28System.String,System.String%29) method expects a path to a file stored in the local file system of the webserver. You can not pass an FTP address here.

Instead, load the file from FTP and serve it from the received FtpStream.

```
try {
    /* Create an FTP Request */
    var ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
    /* Log in to the FTP Server with the User Name and Password Provided */
    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);
    /* When in doubt, use these options */
    ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
    ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
    ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;
    /* Specify the Type of FTP Request */
    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
    /* Establish Return Communication with the FTP Server */
    var ftpResponse = (FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
    /* Get the FTP Server's Response Stream */
    var ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream();

    // TODO: you might need to extract these settings from the FTP response
    const string contentType = "application/zip";
    const string fileNameDisplayedToUser = "FileName.zip"

    return File(ftpStream, contentType, fileNameDisplayedToUser);
}
catch (Exception ex) { 
    _logger.Error(ex); 
}
```

This answer was adopted from [Display an Image from Ftp Server](https://forums.asp.net/post/5770604.aspx).

Comment: How can I download multiple files from FTP in Zip format. The above code works for single file.